# Please Bare as its a duplicate - 'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have gone through many related posts and tried fixing the problem, but no luck. I don't get what I am doing wrong.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
# url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': 'static'}),
# url(r'^api/', include('RESApi.urls')),
# url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
]
```

The admin page says  AttributeError at /admin/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to utilize regular expressions in your code, you must first load the regular expression library to your code, using the statement:

import re

Then, you use this guide for reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: That's not the issue. The question is about `django-url-routing` problem.